# How are rest api created using swagger distributed

Tags: json, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I understand that creation of Rest api documentation using swagger Ui generates a few jsons

Do other developers need to use swagger UI installation on their laptop to view these ?
What is the best way to view such a documentation

Answer (score 0):

The general way is to host your own swagger ui instance on your servers, exposing the REST documentation. When all fails, and assuming you've enabled CORS, you can use the online [petstore](http://petstore.swagger.io) and paste the URL to you Swagger there.